# Asking for a HTML property

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web project these days. When click on a button, I want to open the description as in the below image. I do not want the code for that. I just want only know the name of that option. If anyone know tell me the name of this option. Then I could find a suitable code.[image]

Comment: You're looking for a modal dialog box

Comment: There is no such thing in HTML, you'll have to style it yourself or use some pre-styled 3rd-party implementation.

Comment: As @j08691 stated above, you are looking for a modal. In most css frameworks, they are included. E.g. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com is a better fit for this kind of question btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is called Modal in bootstrap, more details can be found here [Bootstrap Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

please give a try.

Comment: Unsure, but maybe because it doesn't really answer the question?

Comment: @digiwizkid I don't know the reason for downvoting. I think this site is for only experts, not for beginners. I don't downvote your comments. It is automatically happened thing. :-(

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery as mentioned to trigger modal box (they are used in html5 alot) and if you pretend to use it, just learn first how jQuery works and combine with CSS properties :)